# Get `grep` to not output file name

Tags: grep

When I use `grep -o` to search in multiple files, it outputs each result prefixed with the file name. How can I prevent this prefix? I want the results without the file names.

Comment: From `man grep`  `-h, --no-filename`
       Suppress the  prefixing of  filenames  on output when multiple
       files are searched.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

With the GNU implementation of `grep` (the one that also introduced `-o`) or compatible, you can use the `-h` option.

> ```
> -h, --no-filename
>           Suppress the prefixing of file names on  output.   This  is  the
>           default  when there is only one file (or only standard input) to
>           search.
> ```

With other implementations, you can always concatenate the files with `cat` and `grep` that output:

```
cat ./*.txt | grep regexp
```

Or use `sed` or `awk` instead of `grep`:

```
awk '/regexp/' ./*.txt
```

(extended regexps like with `grep -E`).

```
sed '/regexp/!d/' ./*.txt
```

(basic regexps like with `grep` without `-E`. Many `sed` implementations now also support a `-E` option for extended regexps).

Answer (score 1):

With `git grep`, use the `-h` option to suppress file names:

```
git grep -h <pattern>
```

Note that the option `--no-filename` doesn't work with git grep.